# Access Partial views properties in jquery from main view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am creating a step-tour using Tourist with Jquery and in order to move from a step to another I need to use properties from partial views (for example : I have a grid in my main view and the editor of the grid is in a partial view that is displayed when a button is clicked).
I would like to access (using the id or class) the properties of this partial view from my main view (in the jquery script) to be able to create the required steps for the step-tour.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with 'properties of this partial view'? Do you want to access the model or just the DOM elements? In the second case you can just use jQuery from the main view like any other DOM selector: `$("#someIdInPartialView")`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I mean with properties is the dropdownlists and the editors and labels that I have in the partial view. What I want to do is to hide and show a text that exists in the main view while changing the dropdownlist that exist in the partial view

Comment: If your partial view contains let's say a div with text:
`<div id="divWithText">blablabla</div>` then you can simply reach it in your mainview with jQuery as normally:
`var textDiv = $("#divWithText");`